# Hiding ExtJS Grid Column header

Tags: javascript, extjs

I understand I can hide grid column header using the code.

```
#gridid .x-grid3-hd-row { display:none; }
```

But I don't want to use any CSS change. How to do the same using JavaScript?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can do it easily with adding this to **Ext.grid.GridPanel** to this way :

```
hideHeaders: true
```

Answer (score 11):

You can set the [`hideHeaders` configuration option of the `GridPanel`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel) to `true`. Or do you mean after the grid is rendered?

**Edited:** If you want to change (or disable) the way the header is created, you could also override `renderHeaders` or `updateHeaders` from `GridView`. Another way might be to pass a `templates` option to the `GridView`, with the `header` value set to an empty template instead of the default:

```
ts.header = new Ext.Template(
    '',
    '{cells}',
    '
'
);
```

Although the default implementation writes the header in `this.innerHd`, and `innerHd` is defined as `this.mainHd.dom.firstChild`, and `this.mainHd` is set to hidden if if `hideHeaders` option is set. So I would expect that option would affect the column headers too.

**Edited:** What version of ExtJS are we talking about? I looked at [the current source](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/GridView.html), which is 3.1 I guess.

Comment: hideHeader Option is for only Grid's Header. I asked about Grid's column header

Answer (score 6):

just add `hideHeaders: true` to your grid. it should work

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to your grid definition:

```
listeners: {
    render: function(grid) {
        grid.getView().el.select('.x-grid3-header').setStyle('display', 'none');
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you end up wanting this when you put your grid into a panel.

For me the css hacks seemed bad and only this worked:

```
preventHeaders: true
```

See the property [here in the docs.](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-hideHeaders)